# Port Forwarding on Windows 10 using "HNetCfg.NATUPnP"

Tags: delphi, upnp

I am using Delphi XE3 and trying to create a port forwarding (UPnP) using "HNetCfg.NATUPnP". After some research, here is what I got so far:

```
function PortMapAdd(const ExtPort, IntPort: DWORD;
  const IPAdd, Protocol, Descript: string): Boolean;
var
  Nat, Ports: Variant;
begin
  Result := False;
  try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      Nat := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.NATUPnP');
      Ports := Nat.StaticPortMappingCollection;
      if not VarIsClear(Ports) then
      begin
        Ports.Add(ExtPort, UpperCase(Protocol),
          IntPort, IPAdd, True, Descript);
        Result := True;
      end;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
  except
    on E:Exception do raise;
  end;
end;
```

The above code works perfectly on Windows 7, but on Windows 10 `VarIsClear` always returns `true`.

`Application-UPnP` is enabled in my router configuration and `UPnP User Interface (network discovery)` is enabled in Windows 10.

Please, is there any other configuration I must check? Or maybe the code is not compatible with Windows 10? I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Is UPNP turned on on the Win10 computer?

Comment: @fpiette, I turned on network discovery, as explained in this link https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001367.htm . Is this enough? Thanks!

Comment: Network location can't be Public as this can prevent local traffic working due to firewall restrictions.

Comment: @fpiette I changed network from public to private and restarted Windows, but result is the same. Any other tip? Thanks!

Comment: Admin priviledges?

Comment: @fpiette I am already running the application with admin priviledges.

Comment: @Guybrush Microsoft's `NATUPnP` class is just inherently unstable in general, plenty of posts about it not working correctly, or failing randomly.  I would probably find a 3rd party UPnP library (or write my own) and hope it is more stable than Microsoft's implementation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I wish I had enough IQ to create this library :) Do you know any UPnP library to suggest? Do you think using Windows netsh interface portproxy with CreateProcess is a reliable approach? Thanks!

Comment: @Guybrush I use `portproxy` to give a local PC access to a remote PC on a VPN because it cant join a VPN directly. No problems with it. Whether or not `portproxy` will work for you is unclear, since you didn't describe the scenario that you are trying to use `NATUPnP` for in the first place.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you are right, I made mistake with `portproxy` usage. I will research about a UPnP library solution. Thank you again!